# Custom url redirect with params after login fails

Tags: grails, spring-security

I need add url paramater after spring security redirects to `login/authfail` somethig like this `<appname>/login/authfails?id=2523452345`.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use custom `AuthenticationFailureHandler` implementation (with any redirect params you want), instead of default `SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler`.

Answer (score 1):

This has already been answered and accepted but I wanted to go more in depth.

First I extended the default Spring-Security `AjaxAwareAuthenticationFailureHandler`:

```
public class  MyAuthenticationFailureHandler extends AjaxAwareAuthenticationFailureHandler implements InitializingBean {

  def staticFailureUrl

    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationFailure(final HttpServletRequest request, final HttpServletResponse response,
            final AuthenticationException exception) throws IOException, ServletException {

        // Logic to generate id that will be passed with the redirect
        defaultFailureUrl = staticFailureUrl + '&id=2523452345'

        super.onAuthenticationFailure(request, response, exception);
    }
```

Then I use `resources.groovy` to override the default `authenticationFailureHandler` bean with my own implementation.

```
beans = {
    authenticationFailureHandler(MyAuthenticationFailureHandler) {
        redirectStrategy = ref('redirectStrategy')
        staticFailureUrl = application.config.failureHandler.staticFailureUrl
        useForward = application.config.failureHandler.useForward
        ajaxAuthenticationFailureUrl = application.config.failureHandler.ajaxAuthFailUrl
        exceptionMappings = application.config.failureHandler.exceptionMappings
        allowSessionCreation = application.config.failureHandler.allowSessionCreation
    }
}
```

This bean uses several config settings within `Config.groovy`:

```
failureHandler {
    staticFailureUrl = '/login/authfail?login_error=1'
    ajaxAuthFailUrl = '/login/authfail?ajax=true'
    exceptionMappings = [:]
    useForward = false
    allowSessionCreation = true
}
```

Most of these have already been duplicated in `DefaultSecurityConfig.groovy` class in the Spring-Security plugin but I'm not sure how to access the values within `Config.groovy`.

Instead of just using `super.onAuthenticationFailure(request, response, exception)`, you could obviously implement the method yourself and get rid of the `defaultFailureUrl` which seems kind of 'hacky' to change arbitrarily.